# Split BCH out of BTC and then BSV out of BCH?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, blockchain-fork, bitcoin-sv

I have an old Bitcoin wallet from before the BCH split.
I think I can still split the BCH out of it, but then would I be able to split the BSV out of these BCH?
If that's possible, is there a special procedure?

I'm thinking :

1. Send full BTC wallet to some other address (to secure them)
2. Import the private key of the original BTC wallet in Electrum Cash to get the BCH
3. Send the BCH to another address (to secure the BCH)
4. Split the BCH into BSV from the original BCH wallet

Would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All fork coins are tied to same private key. Simply import your private key to a multi-currency wallet like Exodus. This will unlock funds from all chains in one place.

Comment: Would that work from the recovery seed as well? And doing that means that I will be able to control the coins from either my original wallet or Exodus (which supports more), right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.